# Computing Stock forward weights based on returns in timeseries

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have a data frame with tickers and daily returns going forward from that date 7/1/2020 to 7/6/2020
and another dataframe with tickers and starting weights as of 6/30/2020

I would like to create a new dataframe with the dates (6/30/2020 - 7/6/2020) and tickers and forward weights where forward weight is computed as weight[t-1]*return[t]. each ticker will have 1 row for each date.

Can you help me with this problem? Images attached below show the dataframes  Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


fname= "df.csv"
df_res = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=",",header=0 )

[enter image description here][1]
header_list = ["Ticker", "Weight", "dDate"]
dfWorker = pd.read_csv('WORKERCOW.csv', sep=",",header=None, 
names=header_list )
dfWorker['Tickercopy']=dfWorker['Ticker']
dfWorker=dfWorker.set_index('Ticker')
[enter image description here][2]
datelist =df_res['DateTime'].unique()
portWts = pd.DataFrame(data=dfWorker['Weight'],
index=dfWorker.index,columns=datelist)
[enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/avWCV.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLuhB.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lupyB.png
```